# Winter cms 1.2 app,public, resorces folders are missing

Tags: laravel, octobercms, laravel-9

I have recentely install winterCms 1.2 which is based on laravel 9. But in winter CMS app,public,resorces,routes folders are missing. we can't run make:controller command,similar laravel 9. How can I work with winterCms if I want do simple crud.

I just want to use features of Winter cms with basic laravel functionality.

Comment: You need to use plugins to make crud. you can use Plugin Builder - Plugin to build controllers etc..

Comment: How to do it normally like laravel 9.2?

Comment: It's not possible to handle request it like that, you must need to use plugins

Comment: is there any way we can use it in existing project?

Comment: @HardikSatasiya can you help me with the plugin method? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you can check the documentation for route registration `https://wintercms.com/docs/plugin/registration#routing-initialization` from there you can add your own controller and return a response from there

Comment: can we use maatwebsite/excel in wintercms?

Comment: Yes, I guess, you can add that to your plugin using composer.